# Not able to update db record due to Java @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

Since Function1 is transactional, after inserting record1, it is locked.
And hence I am not able to update record1 from function3.
Any solution for this?

```
@Transactional
function1(){
    function2();
    function3();
}

function2(){
    //insert into table1 values(); --record1
}

@Transactional
function3(){
    //update record1 inserted in function2
}
```

Comment: It should work. By default propagation is set to required so function3 should be in the same transaction. So no locking. It seems you are missing some details in your question. Maybe function1 is called in a way that do not start new transaction (like from the same class)?

Comment: Is the class itself marked as @Transactional?

Comment: Could you post the *actual* code?

Comment: @IntelliData no

Comment: @Sankozi it was like function1(){ function4();} function4(){function3();}. And function4 was marked as REQUIRED_NEW. hence was not able to update record.